# Creating a VBA formula using CountIF

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a formula to count based upon 2 conditions.  My logic is wrong - again.

When I (manually) enter enter code the summation formula (COUNTIFS) into correct cell itself, it sums correctly:

```
COUNTIFS(E4:E1362,"Requirement",S4:S1362, "<>4")
```

When I execute the following code line, I do not get any errors, but instead, all the sums are zero.

```
Range("G" & Start(groups) - 1).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(E" & Start(groups) & ":E" & Finish(groups) & "," & "Requirement" & ",S" & Start(groups) & ":S" & Finish(groups) & "," & Chr(34) & "<>4" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

I realized that the COUNTIFS was comparing the value in column S to the string "<>4".  And none of the cells contain that string.  This is why all my values were zero.  I do not want the comparison to be against that string.  I want the comparison to be column S value NOT equal to 4.

So, I changed the line to (and variations to get it to work):

```
Range("G" & Start(groups) - 1).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(E" & Start(groups) & ":E" & Finish(groups) & "," & "Requirement" & ",S" & Start(groups) & ":S" & Finish(groups) & "," & Chr(34) & "<>" & Chr(34) & "4)"
```

So, I am at a loss.  (1) I manually enter the formula and it works.  (2) I build it in VBA, and it does not sum correctly.  (3) I look up how to do build the formula correctly, and I get errors time and time again.  It seems like the only way to get this to work is to keep the quotes within quotes, but I don't want to compare against the string.

Does this make sense?  I'm not liking my worksheet anymore.  It is no longer any fun at all.  :(

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your problem is not quoting `Requirement` in the VBA. SeanC's answer below is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think all the `Chr(34)` are getting in the way of you viewing your formula correctly. try using `""` to make the quote for the formula.

```
.Formula = "=COUNTIFS(E4:E1362,""Requirement"",S4:S1362,""<>4"")"
```

with your `Start` and `Finish` functions, that would change the formula to:

```
.Formula = "=COUNTIFS(E" & Start(groups) & ":E" & Finish(groups) & _
    ",""Requirement"",S" & Start(groups) & ":S" & Finish(groups) & ",""<>4"")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, One of the problem I found there was quite simple, instead using "," you must use ";".
It depends on the version you used, some using "," and some others using ";". you can just try it, I hope it solved your problem.

and second one "Requirement" there, I think you should use double quote instead.

and for your case To meet This condition:

```
COUNTIFS(E4:E1362,"Requirement",S4:S1362, "<>4")
```

Use This:

```
 "=COUNTIF(E" & Start(groups) & ":" & "E" & Finish(groups) & "," & """Requirement""" & "," & "S" & Start(groups) & ":" & "S" & Finish(groups) & "," & """<>4"")"
```

I think it Should Work (if I don't miss any Quotes thought).

Answer (score 0):

... Try removing the chr(34) and the extra quotations - It should look exactly like the "Requirement" criteria:

```
Range("G" & Start(groups) - 1).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(E" & Start(groups) & ":E" & Finish(groups) & ",""Requirement"",S" & Start(groups) & ":S" & Finish(groups) & ",""<>4"")"
```

Comment: I tried a different way of building this formula, and while I did not get any errors, the sums were still zero (meaning that I am still comparing against a string, I think): Range("G" & Start(groups) - 1).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(E" & Start(groups) & ":E" & Finish(groups) & "," & "Requirement" & ",S" & Start(groups) & ":S" & Finish(groups) & ",""<>4"")"

Comment: John - I did exactly what you suggested... still zeros.  Don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Sorry I mis-read your initial post.  When I look at the formula left in the cells, it still has quotes around the <>4.  >:/

Comment: @aerogal, do you want the quotes aroudn the `<>4` or not? your original post showed that there were quotes around it??? - If you want it WITHOUT the quotes, simply change the part in my formula above to `",<>4)"`

Comment: I am not sure anymore :(   I tried it that way, and I got an error.  I've tried so many things to get this to work... I know I'm starting to sound like I'm giving up, and I'm sorry about that.  I've tried so many permutations.  The second condition is to test against a number (i.e., 4).  The first condition is to test against a string (i.e., requirement).  I even tried Range("G" & Start(groups) - 1).Formula = "=COUNT(IF((S" & Start(groups) & ":S" & Finish(groups) & ",""<>4""))"",E" & Start(groups) & ":E" & Finish(groups) & ")" -- of course I get an error with this too.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this.  I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

After running a quick test with your initial code

```
Range("G1").Formula = "=COUNTIFS(E1" & ":E20" & "," & "Requirement" & ",S1" & ":S20" & "," & Chr(34) & "<>4" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

Modified slightly to account for your groups variable cell G1 ends up with the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(E1:E20,requirement,S1:S20,"<>4")
```

which when tested works absolutely fine for your second if statement S1:S20,"<>4".
I would guess that the problem lies with your first statement. What is in your requirement range and what data are you trying to match with.

I set up the requirement named range to be cell D5, I entered a 5 in there and the formula would increment each time I added an extra 5 to the range E1:E20.
I then started typing 4's into the range S1:s20 and this decreased my count.

**edit**
The last thing that I can suggest is to add in a helper column in column F that evaluates row to see if it matches the requirement condition, then it would be a simple matter of making your formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(F1:F20,TRUE,S1:S20,"<>4")
```

Comment: Rick, I want to agree with you.  The problem is that this statement used to be just a "countif" with the initial condition (comparing against requirement).  And it really worked just fine.  I have a spreadsheet full of hundreds of requirements and they are grouped into all these subgroups, each summed correctly within their respective groups.  When I add the 2nd condition (to only count requirements that are not level 4) it blows this to pieces.  I get zero sums.  So frustrating.  Now these requirements have 3 rows allocated to each, which is why the column is testing for "requirement" first.

Comment: Can you give me an example of your requirement data